# Accessing single images within a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

Hi I am new to StackOverflow and hoping to be able to figure out what I need to do to be able to reference an individual image that I created in an array for a scroll view.  Here is the scroll view with the array:

```
int PageCount = 2;

        NSMutableArray *myArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"12-4.png",@"13-4.png",nil];

        scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        scroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
        scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:scroller];
        width=scroller.frame.size.width;
        xPos=0;
        for (int i=0; i<PageCount; i++)
        {
            ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height)];
            [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
            [scroller addSubview:ImgView];
            scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
            width +=scroller.frame.size.width;
            xPos  +=scroller.frame.size.width;
        }
```

And then with an if statement I would like to be able to determine which image I am currently on in the scroll view and I tried it like this:

```
if (ImgView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:[arrImageName objectAtIndex:0]])
        {
            NSLog(@"Yes");   
        }
```

Trying to see if the user is on the first image by `objectAtIndex:0`however unfortunately this did not work.  What would I need to do in the if statement to determine that the user is on the first photo?  Thank you!

Comment: For your `if`, what is `ImgView` set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do you calculations based on the page size and the `contentOffset' of the scroll view. Trying to compare the images will be much harder and far less reliable.

Comment: so in the case of knowing if the user is on the first image using `if (scroller.contentOffset.x == 0)` is a good way of doing it?

Comment: The offset might not be exactly equal to 0 so you should define a range of values that are acceptable. What if the user is in the middle of a scroll...

Comment: thats true, thank you! So do you know if the offset for the first photo is just going to be equal to the size of my iPhone?  The width of the photo is 320 so now I have `if (scroller.contentOffset.x >=0<320)`

Comment: Yes, but you should base it on the frame of the scroll view because that is what actually defines the page size.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything. I would really appreciate help on a followup [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582237/display-content-on-sections-of-uiscrollview)