# Display Content on Sections of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to hide content on only one section (one photo) of my UIScrollView and am using a `contentOffset`to access that section like below.  If the content offset is between 0 and 320 (the size of my image) I am hiding various elements on the screen.  However when the user swipes over to the next photo (i.e. content offset greater than 320) I would like to show the content again.  The first portion of my code works great, however I am not sure that there is any detection of the content offset being greater than 320 when the user swipes.  I am fairly new with ScrollViews and am not sure if they update the content offset constantly or whether they detect user swipe that would cause an update.  Are there any ideas on how I can get the elements hidden to equal NO after the user has scrolled beyond my first image?

```
  if (scroller.contentOffset.x >=0<=320)
                {
                    preview.hidden = YES;
                    share.hidden = YES;
                    barView.hidden = YES;
                    saveButton.hidden = YES;
                    shaddows.hidden = YES;

                }
                else if (scroller.contentOffset.x >320)
                {
                   //This part does not work
                    preview.hidden = NO;
                    share.hidden = NO;
                    barView.hidden = YES;
                    saveButton.hidden = YES;
                    shaddows.hidden = YES;
                }
```

Here is the rest of my scroller code:

```
int PageCount = 2;

        NSMutableArray *myArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"12-4.png",@"13-4.png",nil];

        scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        scroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
        scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:scroller];
        width=scroller.frame.size.width;
        xPos=0;
        for (int i=0; i<PageCount; i++)
        {
            ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height)];
            [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
            [scroller addSubview:ImgView];
            scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
            width +=scroller.frame.size.width;
            xPos  +=scroller.frame.size.width;
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just deleted "xcode" because Xcode is just the IDE not related in this case.

Comment: Thank you I am learning!

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you're after here. Can you post some images that depict what you're trying to do?

Comment: Well basically I am trying to have one section of a UIScrollView trigger some buttons and images to appear and then when you scroll to a different section hide them.  I am thinking I can use offset values to decide where the user is on the scroll view.  Does that help?  I will be happy to edit my question and make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
  if (scroller.contentOffset.x >=0<=320)
```

To

```
  if (scroller.contentOffset.x <= 320)
```

Because the original doesn't do what you think it will.

This code should be in the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method (make sure your controller is the scroll view delegate).

Add some log statements so it prints out as the user is scrolling what the content offset it and what page your code thinks it is.